# AWS throttling based on Cognito token

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Is it possible to throttle requests based on token granted by Amazon Cognito? Scenario is, that no external identity provider is used. Still I would like to limit calls to my API Gateway based on Identity ID assigned to user by Cognito.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, API Gateway only supports Stage/Method level, API Key level and its own account level throttling. If you really want this feature to be implemented, please submit a feature request via AWS Support.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your use case correctly, what you are looking for is already [supported](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html) with little setup / effort.

I've used that setup to only allow calls to certain endpoints exposed by API Gateway from users in specific pools in Cognito.

Comment: How would you throttle requests in this solution?

Comment: @ub_marco I would use one of the standard methods https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-request-throttling.html or an external provider e.g. Cloudflare/Akamai/Imperva etc

Comment: The link I provided lists various ways of throttling. The contents may have changed since the original post in 2022, but after skimming it still seems to be containing relevant content.